# Why is IsDBNull throwing a conversion overflow exception?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a pretty simple code snippet here that is causing me a lot of problems. I also want to mention that using statements should be used, but the code was not originally authored by me. I'll likely fix this at some point

```vb
            Dim dbShippableOpenOrders As New sqlCommand(sqlText, objConn)
            Dim rsShippableOpenOrders As sqlDataReader = dbShippableOpenOrders.executeReader
```

...

```
                If IsDBNull(rsShippableOpenOrders("cost")) Then
                    cost = 0
                Else
                    cost = rsShippableOpenOrders("cost")
                End If
```

I can't seem to figure out why this code is producing the following error message:

> Conversion overflows.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred
> during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
> stack trace for more information about the error and where it
> originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.OverflowException: Conversion overflows.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 355:                End If 
> Line 356: 
> Line 357:                If IsDBNull(rsShippableOpenOrders("cost")) Then 
> Line 358:                    cost = 0 
> Line 359:                Else
> ```

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question you've asked but you should not be using that `IsDBNull` method to begin with. The data reader has it's own method for detecting NULLs so use that: `cost = If(rsShippableOpenOrders.IsDBNull(rsShippableOpenOrders.GetOrdinal("cost")), 0, rsShippableOpenOrders.GetInt32(rsShippableOpenOrders.GetOrdinal("cost")))`.

Comment: By the way, have you actually confirmed that `IsDBNull` is the issue? You should have done this already to confirm but try getting the field value first and assigning it to a variable and then look at it in the debugger to see what it actually contains. It that works, then you can pass that variable to `IsDBNull`. If you're correct then the exception will be thrown on that second operation, but I doubt that it will be.

Comment: @jmcilhinney This is running on an old IIS server and I don't have access to any debugging or anything at all on the server levels. The only thing I can do is look at the DB and edit these old aspx files.

Also, cost needs to be a floating point value, it can't be an int.

Comment: Where is `cost` declared?

Comment: “This is running on an old IIS server and I don't have access to any debugging or anything at all on the server levels. The only thing I can do is look at the DB and edit these old aspx files “
A way in that “spartan” conditions is that you can create in that Server a Folder Full permission Read/Write. A log file is always a plus for you.

Comment: What kind of database is it? SQL Server? mySQL? Look at the data type for "cost" in VB.NET and also the data type for cost as defined in the database.

Comment: Can you change the SQL query to use `COALESCE(cost, 0)` instead of `cost`, or do you need to use the information that the column is `NULL` in the database in the program?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Dim cost As Decimal = 0
Dim dbShippableOpenOrders As New SqlCommand(sqlText, objConn)
Dim rsShippableOpenOrders As SqlDataReader = dbShippableOpenOrders.ExecuteReader()

If rsShippableOpenOrders.HasRows Then
    While rsShippableOpenOrders.Read()
        If rsShippableOpenOrders("cost") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(rsShippableOpenOrders("cost")) Then
            cost = CDec(rsShippableOpenOrders("cost"))
        Else
            cost = 0
        End If
    End While
End If
```

Here's a sample method:

```
Public Sub GetDataTblProduct(connectionStr As String)

    Dim sqlText As String = "Select * from Product"
    Dim cost As Decimal = 0

    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionStr)
        'open
        con.Open()

        Using dbShippableOpenOrders As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlText, con)
            Using rsShippableOpenOrders As SqlDataReader = dbShippableOpenOrders.ExecuteReader
                If rsShippableOpenOrders.HasRows Then
                    While rsShippableOpenOrders.Read()
                        If rsShippableOpenOrders("cost") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(rsShippableOpenOrders("cost")) Then
                            cost = CDec(rsShippableOpenOrders("cost"))
                        Else
                            cost = 0
                        End If

                        'Debug.WriteLine("cost: " & cost)
                    End While
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```